# How can I write a macro to check to for a related record in another table?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I would like to write a macro that will run every time a record is entered into a certain table.  What I want the macro to do is check to see if there is a related record in a different table, and if so, to change a field of data type Yes/No to Yes.  If no related record is defined yet, I would do nothing, as the default for the Yes/No field is No.

The two tables are related in [this way.](http://www.prayingmantesconcepts.com/access2010/relationships.png)

So when a record is entered in to the tblOrders table, I need to check if a related record exists in the tblRecipes table, and I would like to use a macro to do so if possible, as I will be repeating this action for every Order entered.

Is this possible, and if so, what would the macro language be please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual thing would be to use forms for data entry and to check the Recipes table in the before update event for the control, for example.

```
Private Sub CustomerPartNumber_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not IsNull(DLookup( _
     "CustPartNum", "tblRecipes", "CustPartNum=" & Me.CustomerPartNumber)) Then
        Me.AYesNoField = True
    Else
        Me.AYesNoField = False
    End If
End Sub
```

However, in Access 2010, you can use [data macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx). This example will run whenever CustomerPartNumber is changed in Orders.

[image: before change data macro]

Comment: Actually I do use a form for data entry.  In that case then you would recommend using the VBA code in your first example rather than the data macro?

Comment: Yes, if you are working within MS Access, use VBA, it will give you more control. I have shown the Before Update event in case you need to cancel the update, but if all you are doing is changing the YesNo field, After Update is just as good.

Comment: Right.  What I wasn't sure how to do was verify the existence of another record.  Clearly that is achieved through the DLookup, which I will now investigate thoroughly.  Incidentally, you saved my rear.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I have another issue.  When I try the VBA code I get an error that says, "Run-time error '3464':  Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

I have double checked both data types in the tables and they are both text fields with field sizes of 20.  What could be causing this error please?

Comment: For text, you need quotes: `"CustPartNum", "tblRecipes", "CustPartNum='" & Me.CustomerPartNumber & "'"`

Comment: That was it!  Truly, thank you so much for your help and quick response.

Comment: Ok another question for you please.  In my Order Entry form, I would like a combo box that will list Company Names from tblCustomer in a dropdown to choose from.  I am not sure the best way to do this, as the primary key in tblCustomers is an AutoNumber datatype.  I want the Order Entry Form to store in tblOrders the name of the Company and not the CustomerID.  Thoughts?

Comment: You should not store the name of the Company, it will lead to problems, you should store the ID, you cam always get the name from a query. You cam set up you combo with a row source `select id, company from customers` -- `column widths 0;2` -- `column count 2` -- `bound column 1` bound column is the value that will be stored to the field set in `control source`

Comment: Ok works like a charm.  Now if I want to display the Company Name rather than the ID on a report, how would I do so?

Comment: Use a query as the basis of the report: `select company, orderdetail from orders inner join customers on customers.id=orders.customerid`, assuming only a customer can have an order, if orders do not always have an associated customer, you need a `left join`

Comment: I do have a query as the basis of the report right now.  Here is the SQL:

SELECT tblOrders.SalesOrderNumber, tblOrders.Customer, tblOrders.PONumber, tblOrders.OrderDate, tblOrders.DueDate, tblOrders.CustomerPartNumber, tblOrders.FONumber, tblOrders.Alloy, tblOrders.Temper, tblOrders.Finish, tblRecipes.StepOne, tblRecipes.StepTwo, tblRecipes.StepThree, 
FROM tblRecipes INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblRecipes.CustPartNum = tblOrders.CustomerPartNumber
WHERE (((tblOrders.FONumber)=[FO Number?]));

What change do I need to  make so that the Customer Name shows up and not the ID?

Comment: Like: `SELECT tblOrders.SalesOrderNumber, tblOrders.Customer, tblOrders.PONumber, tblOrders.OrderDate, tblOrders.DueDate, tblOrders.CustomerPartNumber, tblOrders.FONumber, tblOrders.Alloy, tblOrders.Temper, tblOrders.Finish, tblRecipes.StepOne, tblRecipes.StepTwo, tblRecipes.StepThree
FROM (tblRecipes 
INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblRecipes.CustPartNum = tblOrders.CustomerPartNumber)
INNER JOIN tblCustomers ON tblOrders.Customer = tblCustomers.ID
WHERE tblOrders.FONumber=[FO Number?]` Use the query design window to get it right.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks again.  Sorry to hassle!

Comment: If you would like I would like to thank you for your help.  I have a $20 gift card to Amazon that is yours if you want it.  I know it isn't much but I greatly appreciate your help.  Let me know how you would like for me to get you the card number please!

Comment: You are very kind indeed and I thank you, but I do not help in any expectation of reward. Pay the help forward if you wish :)

Comment: I have one more question that is along the same lines as the original post but different functionality.  I have a form that uses a combo box with a query as its record source to view all records in tblOrders where HasRecipeFlag = No.  I have a subform on that form with a record source of tblRecipes, and when I save a record on that subform, I want to update all records in tblOrders with that CustPartNum, changing the HasRecipeFlag to Yes.  Any ideas, or do you need a little more information?